# How to make certain input fields appear when selected certain option in html?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a web form and here i want to make it so that you can select one of the three given types of options of contact and based on it a respective input field appears.How can i achieve that?

```
<select id="contact">
  <option value="address">Address</option>
  <option value="phone">Phone number</option>
  <option value="website">Website</option>
</select>
```

i tried this at first but didnt know how to proceed further:

```
<form name="address" id="address" style="display:none">
      <input type="text" name="address_"><br>
</form>
<form name="phone" id="phone" style="display:none">
      <input type="text" name="phone_"><br>
</form>
<form name="website" id="website" style="display:none">
      <input type="text" name="website_"><br>
</form>
```

Comment: Welcome on SO! Please show us what you've tried to do this so that we can provide valuable answers. I'm quite sure there are plenty of tutorials on the web for you to start coding it.

Comment: @ichigo14 If an answer on this page solved your problem please consider marking it as accepted. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add an onselect handler to the option fields. Then inside the handler, call a function to append a dom node. Something like this:

```
<option value="address" onselect="handleSelection">Address</option>

function handleSelection() { 
    document.body.appendChild(someDomNode)
}
```

Comment: Same logic, but already print the input as hidden. Than, the function onselect will set `display: block` or `display: none`.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to set the `onchange` `EventListener` to the parent `<select id="contact">` element than it is to set a `onselected` or some other `EvenListener` to each of the `<option>` elements.

**Note:** I separated the javascript logic a little bit so it's easier to read.

```js
document.getElementById('contact').addEventListener('change', function(e){
  let value = e.target.value;
  removeCreatedElements();   // remove all previously added, if any, before adding a new one
  let input = createElement(value);
  document.body.appendChild(input);
  input.style.display = "block";
})

function createElement(value) {
  let input = document.createElement("input");
  input.type = "text";
  input.id = value;
  input.classList.add("dynamically-added");
  input.placeholder = value;
  return input;
}

function removeCreatedElements() {
  let inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".dynamically-added");
  for(let i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    document.body.removeChild(inputs[i]);
  }
}
```

```css
#contact {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<select id="contact">
  <option value="address">Address</option>
  <option value="phone">Phone number</option>
  <option value="website">Website</option>
</select>
```